# Comments with Umlauts in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ddl

In my DDL I have German Umlauts (ä, ö, ü) in the comments for table/fieldnames:

```
CREATE TABLE "table1"
(
  "field1" CHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
COMMENT ON TABLE "table1" IS 'Wörter';
```

When I look at the generated SQL in pgAdmin after execution of the DDL, the Umlauts are displayed as follows:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE table1 IS 'WÃ¶rter';
```

How can I achive that the Umlauts are displayed properly?

Comment: Encoding of the database? Version of the pgAdmin? Result of `select * from pg_description where objoid = 'table1'::regclass;` (using `psql` please)?

Comment: How exactly did you _run_ that DDL statement? If it was a SQL script then maybe the script's encoding was wrong.

Comment: Database encoding: UTF8, pgAdmin 4. I run the DDL statement as SQL script (UTF-8 encoding).